# Retrieving Session Data From Laravel Users in the Console

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.5, laravel-session

Due to a bug, some data didn't record from the session at the time a user logged in the first time. That session's data is still there and needs recording in the appropriate places within the database.

Is there any way to retrieve user session data using the information from the user's table while in the console?

Redis currently handles the sessions.

Comment: Can you use Laravel Tinker to see the session's data?

Comment: @KarlHill how would I do that?

Comment: If you have Laravel 5.7 Tinker is already available for use (check composer.json). If not add it. Then you can run 'php artisan tinker' and start testing your Laravel code. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-tinker

Comment: @KarlHill Tinker has been available for a lot longer than that Laravel version and I'm well acquainted with it. If I had any idea how to pull the session data from the user object I could already test it in many other ways than simply using Tinker. I'm looking for help beyond using this basic tool.

Comment: How do you know it is there? Do you know the Redis key?

Comment: @Mozammil the data value I'm looking for is always saved, so it is there, but it shows up in the session as simply `link`. This can be easily accessed using `Session::get('link')` while the user is active. I need to access it by somehow relating it to an ID on the `users` table.